# Remix unable to send enough wei

Tags: solidity, remix

I defined my method as: (for simplicity)

```
function exampleOfPassingWeiAsArgument(uint amount) public returns (uint roundId) {
    // More than 0.01 ETH
    require(amount > 10000000000000000);
}
```

But when I pass the following value using remix UI: "11000000000000000",

I get the following error:

> Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed

When I pass one zero less: "1100000000000000" it gets through but I crash obviously due to the "require" check as I am sending too few amount in Wei:

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.

BTW: I am not trying to perform a transfer just pass Wei amount of ether as a function argument.

Any idea why I can't pass uint 11000000000000000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remix hates large numbers and addresses.

For some reason the remix UI has problems with big numbers and addresses.

I find that any big numbers, or addresses I enter into the text boxes will need to be quoted when I put them into the remix UI:

[image: remix-large-number.png]

This is bizarre as the Javascript console itself and `JSON.parse()` don't seem to have any issues with numbers this big.

However with remix once the number is quoted it will work properly, just like magic.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaah and I thought I am crazy or don't understand how Wei and uint works... thx man. Works like a charm. I wanted to raise/fix the issue so I just checked Github and the issue is already addressed by someone else actually.

Comment: Yeah, it got me at the beginning too. I initially thought it was something to do with javascript and exceeding the 32 bit signed integer size... but even with one less zero, it's still way bigger than 2.1bn.

Comment: I also didn't see any error in the console so I was like... must be doing something wrong haha.